# Can Service class have repositories of other entities?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Let's say we have `Entity A` and `Entity B`.
Can I directly call repository methods of `Entity A` from `Service B`?
Or I need to do it like this `Service B` -> `Service A` -> `Repository A`.

The problem is that I have DTOs and all service methods return dtos. but for my `Service B` I need an actual object, what to do in that kind of situation?

Answer (score 2):

IMO It is better to have a specific method in your Service A for your use case for Service B.
Or you can create a separate DTO for service B requirement and return that with a new method from service A.
In any case you should not use repository A from service B.